# How to add customdata to a plotly Scattermapbox plot

Tags: python, hover, plotly

I am displaying different climatic measuring stations in a map with `go.Scattermapbox`. Now I would like to include multiple different values in the hover by using `customdata` in the `hovertemplate` command.
This works fine for values that are part of the graph (like lat, lon) but I can not figure out how to make the `customdata` command work with external data (e.g. adding values for altitude in the hover box).

```
plot_data = [
    go.Scattermapbox(
        lon=data_slctd["longitude"], 
        lat=data_slctd["latitude"], 
        mode="markers", 
        text = data_slctd.site_name.tolist(), 
        hovertemplate =  "<b>%{text}</b><br><br>" + "longitude: %{lon:.2f}<br>" + "latitude: %{lat:.2f}<br>" + "altitude: %{customdata[0]:.0f}<br>"+ "ppm: %{marker.color:.2f}<extra></extra>",
    )
]
```

As explained in the tutorial https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scattermapbox.html (under "Adding other data to the hover with customdata and a hovertemplate")
I have tried to include the `customdata == np.dstack((hover_1, hover_2))` command within the `go.Scattermapbox` but trying to access the first values for hover_1 in the hovertemplate with `%customda[0}:.0f` did not work.

hover_1 and hover_2 hold the values for altitude respective measuring methods for all stations displayed (i.e. each has the same length as the number of stations).

That's what the hover looks like:

[Screenshot of exemplary hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PsTm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't ever set 'customdata' parameter in Scattermapbox. You should modify your code like this:

```
my_customdata = []  # something you want to hover
plot_data = [
    go.Scattermapbox(
        lon=data_slctd["longitude"], 
        lat=data_slctd["latitude"], 
        mode="markers", 
        text=data_slctd.site_name.tolist(), 
        customdata=my_customdata,
        hovertemplate="<b>%{text}</b><br><br>" + "longitude: %{lon:.2f}<br>" + "latitude: %{lat:.2f}<br>" + "altitude: %{customdata[0]:.0f}<br>"+ "ppm: %{marker.color:.2f}<extra></extra>",
    )
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the `customdata` was not displayed because the length of the `customdata` array did not match with the length of the `lat` and `lon` variables.
When you do `customdata[0]`, you are trying to get the first element of the sublist of the `customdata` array.
For example, if you have

```py
x = [1,2,3],
y = [3,4,5]
```

in a plotly figure, then `customdata` should be something like:

```py
customdata = [
  ["a", "b"],
  ["c", "d"],
  ["e", "f"],
]
```

That way when you do `customdata[0]` and hover on `(1,3)` you will get `a`.
If you hover on `2,4` and do `customdata[1]` you will get `d`.